# Cant run net-core docker container though VS2015

Tags: docker, .net-core

After adding Docker support to a .net core app I try to debug the app in docker and get the following error:

Failed to run the command: "c:[project location]\src[appname]\Docker\DockerTask.ps1 -Run -Enviroment Debug -Machine 'default' -OpenSite $False -RemoteDebugging $True", Click for more details.

The docker container has started not sure what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn out its because I am using Docker for windows beta.

You need to go to the Properties folder under your app and edit the Docker.props file.

Default:

```
<!-- Use this property to change the docker host that is used by this project. Delete default, leaving the value blank for the Docker for Windows beta
    (Note: you need to restart VS after changing this property) -->
<DockerMachineName Condition=" '$(DockerMachineName)'=='default' "></DockerMachineName>
```

As the hit says remove the default from the DockerMachineName.  NOTE: I have had to restart my pc to get it to work.

Edited:

```
<DockerMachineName Condition=" '$(DockerMachineName)'=='' "></DockerMachineName>
```